# Display lines inbetween text with grep

Tags: text-processing, grep

I know that I can use the -A and -B command for grep to get a lot of what I am looking for however that is not quite what I want.

I am looking to parse the httpd.conf file **to search for a domain**. Then **display everything between the VirtualHost tags for that domain**. A example of the virtualhost is as follows.

To search for a domain I run the following command:

```
less /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf |grep domain.tld
```

But that does not give me the full virtualhost only the lines that contain the domain.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCACertificateFile /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    SuexecUserGroup anzenketh wheel
    ServerName     anzenketh.net
    ServerAlias    www.anzenketh.net
    ServerAdmin    root@anzenketh.net
    DocumentRoot   /home/anzenketh/www/anzenketh.net
    ScriptAlias    /cgi-bin/ "/home/anzenketh/www/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory /home/anzenketh/www/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride None
        Options ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    CustomLog      /var/log/httpd/anzenketh/anzenketh.net-access_log combined
    ErrorLog       /var/log/httpd/anzenketh/anzenketh.net-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3):

Must use `grep`? `sed` and `awk` are more suitable for such tasks:

```
sed -n '/<VirtualHost /,/<\/VirtualHost>/p' inputfile
awk '/<VirtualHost /,/<\/VirtualHost>/' inputfile
```

As httpd.conf directives are case-insensitive, you may prefer to use case-insensitive matching:

```
sed -n '/<VirtualHost /I,/<\/VirtualHost>/Ip' inputfile
gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 '/<VirtualHost /,/<\/VirtualHost>/' inputfile
```

(`IGNORECASE` is GNU extension, only available in `gawk`.)

**Update** according to the changed question:

```
sed -n '/<VirtualHost\s\+192\.168\.1\.10\b/I,/<\/VirtualHost>/Ip' inputfile
gawk -vIGNORECASE=1 '/<VirtualHost\s+192\.168\.1\.10\>/,/<\/VirtualHost>/' inputfile
```

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. Does not fulfill the requirement of searching for the domain.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/sed-display-text/) is a `sed` call to get everything between (and including) two specific strings:

```
sed -n '/<VirtualHost*/,/<\/VirtualHost>/p' httpd.conf
```

If you want to search for a specific domain, just add it:

```
sed -n '/<VirtualHost 192.168.1.10:80>*/,/<\/VirtualHost>/p' httpd.conf
```

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. Does not fulfill the requirement of searching for the domain.

Comment: You can just add the domain you are searching for, I updated my answer.

Comment: That will find the IP not the domain.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/Iowa/,/Montana/' file
```

Replace string A and B to your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Pzio '(?s)<VirtualHost ([yourserverip]|\*)(:(80|443))?>(?:.(?!</VirtualHost))*?ServerName +[yourservername](?:(?!</VirtualHost).)*?</VirtualHost>' [yourfilename]
```

Replace all contents within [] with correct values

Comment: You should strongly consider adding some explanation of your solution so that new users can learn from your example rather than just copying/pasting.